# Postgres connection in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am struggling to establish a connection inside data iteration. Means I am running a select query to postgres and iterating the return data. after some transformation I am writing it to another table. But it is not working. Sample python code is below.

```
conn = pgconn(------)
cursor = pgconn.Cursor()
query1 = "select * from table"
query2 = "select * from table2 where Id=(%s);"

cursor.execute(query1)
result = query1.fetchall()
for row in result:
    If row.a == 2:
         cursor.execute(query2, [row.time])
```

In the above python code I can't able to extract the data by running query2 and passing query1 result as a parameter. It seems cursor is blocked by the query1 so query2 execution is not happening. Please some one help in this issue.

Comment: Please post a tested example.  You are calling fetchall() on a string, which of course cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can write a join statement to do this and can get the data easily

```
select * from table join table2 where table2.id == table.time
```

Also why this is not working maybe because the cursor object is getting override inside the for loop and thus the query results get changed.

Comment: I can't join the queries because there are lot more steps inbetween these two queries. So I need a solution to execute other query while iterating one query result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RealDictCursor`, and correct the syntax on your inside call to `execute()`:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

conn = pgconn(------)
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
query1 = "select * from table"
query2 = "select * from table2 where Id=(%s);"

cursor.execute(query1)
result = query1.fetchall()
for row in result:
    If row.a == 2:
         cursor.execute(query2, (row['time'],))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. install psycopg2 and psycopg2.extras.** ( pip install)
Then set up your Postgres Connection like:

```
 def Postgres_init(self):

        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect(host=os.environ['SD_POSTGRES_SERVER'],
                                    user=os.environ['SD_POSTGRES_USER'],
                                    password=os.environ['SD_POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
                                    port=os.environ['SD_POSTGRES_PORT'],
                                    database=os.environ['SD_POSTGRES_DATABASE'])
            logging.info("Connected to PostgreSQL")

        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
            logging.info(error)
```

**2. Connect your Cursor with the defined connection**

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

**3. Execute your query:**

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT (column1) from tablename WHERE column2 =%s""", (
                    Value,))  # Check if already exists
                result = cursor.fetchone()
```

Now the value is stored in the "result" variable. Now you can execute the next query like:

```
cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO tablename2
            (column1, column2, column3)
            VALUES
                (%s, %s, %s)
            ON CONFLICT(column1) DO UPDATE
            SET
                column2=excluded.column2,
                column3=excluded.column3;
                   """, (result, column2, column3)
                       )
```

Now the result of query 1 is stored in the second table in the first column.
Now you can close your connection:

```
conn.close()
```